# CFRunLoopRunInMode is exiting with code 1, as if nothing was added

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I have created a CGEventTap like this:

```
GetCurrentProcess(psn);

var mask =  1 << kCGEventLeftMouseDown | // CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown)
            1 << kCGEventLeftMouseUp | 
            1 << kCGEventRightMouseDown |
            1 << kCGEventRightMouseUp |
            1 << kCGEventOtherMouseDown |
            1 << kCGEventOtherMouseUp |
            1 << kCGEventScrollWheel;

mouseEventTap = CGEventTapCreateForPSN(&psn, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, mask, null);

if (!mouseEventTap.isNull()) {
      aRLS = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, mouseEventTap, 0);
      CFRelease(mouseEventTap);

      if (!aRLS.isNull()) {
            aLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

            CFRunLoopAddSource(aLoop, aRLS, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

            CFRelease(aRLS);
            CFRelease(aLoop);

            rez = CFRunLoopRunInMode(ostypes.CONST.kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 10, false); // figure out how to make this run indefinitely
            // rez is 1 :(

      }

}
```

My `CFRunLoopRun` is exiting immediately, instead of running for 10seconds. And it says code is 1 which means no sources are in that mode. But I clearly did a `CFRunLoopAddSource` to the common modes option `kCFRunLoopRunFinished. The run loop mode mode has no sources or timers.`. Anyone know whats up? This is on not-main thread.

Comment: Shouldn't you put the runloop code in `do while` ?
I am not an expert but when I messed with runloops I came to something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064115/obj-c-configure-run-loop-for-nsdistributionnotificationcenter

Comment: Thanks @user3351949 yes I should for `CFRunLoopRunInMode` because it has an interval. If I used `CFRunLoopRun` I wouldnt have to as that runs indefinitely. But I needed `CFRunLoopRunInMode` because I neeeded it to run in the mode of `kCFRunLoopCommonModes`, I dont think we can do indefinite run in that mode with `CFRunLoopRun` but if we can that would be best. But i nthis case no loop is needed as I am just testing to see if that loop goes for `10` seconds as thats what the interval is, but its not going for that much it keeps exiting wiht code `1` thinking that it has no sources.

Comment: Do you own aLoop and do you have to release it?

Comment: Ah Im not sure. Ill test without releasing. aLoop is just the current thread. I spawned a thread, so the thread is mine. Im not sure what it means to own aLoop. But will test wihout releasing it and report back thanks Willeke :)

Comment: @Willeke I tried it but still same problem :(

Comment: @Willeke solution found below! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a run loop in `kCFRunLoopCommonModes`. This is clearly stated in the documentation for `CFRunLoopRunInMode()`.

`kCFRunLoopCommonModes` is a virtual mode. It's basically a set of other modes. It can only be used when adding (or removing) a source to a run loop to say "monitor this source when the run loop is run in any of the modes in the set". But when you run a run loop, you have to run it in a specific, real mode, not this virtual mode which represents a set of other modes.

I recommend that, when you're working on a private thread and only want to monitor private sources, that you add the source to a custom mode and run the run loop in that mode. A custom mode is just a string with a unique value. For example, something like "com.yourcompany.yourproject.yourmodespurpose". Using a custom mode makes sure that the run loop never does anything unexpected, like firing a source added by the frameworks.

You must not release `aLoop`. Functions that don't have "Create" or "Copy" in their name do not give you ownership.

You will need a loop around your call to `CFRunLoopRunInMode()` because it will return every time it handles an event from your source (`kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource` == 4) or hits the timeout (`kCFRunLoopRunTimedOut` == 3). You should break out of the loop if it ever returns anything else.

Comment: Just woke up and sooo happy to see this thank you Ken! Will test out right away! :)

Comment: Thanks so much ken its exiting now with code 3 for timeout, Ill spend some more time on it and update you why its not exiting with code 4 for handled its very interesting.

Comment: Yesss it works!! I just had to fix up my masks, without your thing this would have never worked! Thank you so much!!! Here is my solution: https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl/blob/3a85e748b6e1725dc019b048c13303c3320597bf/modules/workers/MMSyncWorker.js#L788-L834

Comment: Just double checking, there is no way to make CFRunLoopRunInMode go indefinitely, like set 2nd arg to largest number that fits in `CFTimeInterval` type? Other then the while loop method? Is it possible to like set mode, then use `CFRunLoopRun`?

Comment: If you want to run the run loop in a mode other than the default mode, then you have to use `CFRunLoopRunInMode()`. You can specify a very large timeout and false for `returnAfterSourceHandled` and it should run for a long time without you writing a loop around it. I probably still would, for completeness.